# validateDOMNesting(...): #text cannot appear as a child of <tr>

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am creating a reusable component for table and I am facing the warning in console that is:-

```
validateDOMNesting(...): #text cannot appear as a child of <tr>.
```

Here is the sample code :-

This is render method in which we are checking the value of object if json then make the linkable row otherwise simple text.

```
return (
   <div className="table-responsive" id={self.props.tableId}>
       <table id="table3"className="table table-bordered">
           <tbody>
              {
                 this.isJson(self.props.columns.labels[0]) ?
                     (this.props.records.map((record, index) => {
                         return self.makeLink( record, index)
                     })) : (this.props.records.map((record, index) => {
                         return ( <tr key = { index } > {
                             self.props.columns.labels.map((label, index) => {
                                 return ( <td key = { index } > { self.renderTableData(index, record) } </td>)
                             })
                         } </tr> )
                     }))
             }

           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>                          
   );
```

makeLink function :-

```
  makeLink(record, index){
    var self = this;
    return (
       <tr key={index} onClick={this.redirect.bind(this,record._id)} >
       {this.props.columns.labels.map((label, index) =>{
           return (
              <td key={index}>{self.renderTableData(index,record)}</td>
            )
       })}
   </tr> 
 )
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Just as the error says, you can't have text directly inside `<tr>`, you have to put it inside a `<th>` or `<td>`.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am doing the same yet it is throwing the warning

Comment: Edit your question and insert an example of your code, blind instructions would point you nowhere.

Comment: I have edited my question with detailed description. may it will be helpful now